# Rest Assured: Cannot determine which path implementation to use error

Tags: rest, cucumber, rest-assured

I am getting the following error line when trying to extract a response:

> Cannot determine which path implementation to use because the
> content-type application/octet-stream doesn't map to a path
> implementation.

The response is:

```
{
    "status": "ok"
}
```

which obviously resembles a JSON format.

So, I try the following:

```
requestSpecification.contentType(ContentType.JSON);
```

before running the request, and

```
RestAssured.registerParser("application/octet-stream", Parser.JSON);
String acutual_val = response.then().extract().path("status");
```

afterwards.

But I get the error message above.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.then().extract().jsonPath().get(path);
```

Comment: path should be "status" ?

Comment: Unfortunately it returned a null string.

Comment: I faced this issue and the problem was that the response was null. Try to print the response before the validation to have better clarification. Thanks @dushkin